# See the difference between a clean laravel install and my code

Tags: laravel, diff

I have a laravel app in which I want to see the added/changed files

How can I compare my Laravel project to a clean Laravel installation? Is there some software that can achieve this or should I write a script?

Comment: I believe you should write a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt theres something like that specifically for Laravel. However, what you can do is to use Version Control (git) to help if your plan is to compare these 2 projects (Fresh install vs Project)

> https://git-scm.com/

I'd do the following steps:

1. Create a git repo
2. Place a fresh laravel install on the repo
3. git add . and create a commit
4. Replace the whole directory with the new project
5. View with git diff (SourceTree would help you)

Git diff would give you what files are changed (in regards to the fresh install) and what differs in code. Beware that since we're talking about a Laravel project with a lot of content and a fresh install, it will give a lot of files changed.